# What is this "adsgo-frame" class in my Chrome Dom Tree?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have an iframe loaded every time I open a new webpage and it adds adsgo-frame class to all my elements. I first suspect it being part of adblock but then I found it exists even without adblock enabled. Is it a builtin feature of Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the pandora auto clicker. It uses adsgo.com's framework to complete the auto-click request. It might also be able to track your activities so I would disable it or remove it.